# How to move a variable from one class to another in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple RPG game and I wonder how to move stat values from CharacterCreator class to player class without inheritance.Down here are .h and .cpp files. Probably very easy thing but I really don't know.

**CharacterCreator.h**

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<string>

class CharacterCreator
{
private:

    //Variables defining CharacterCreator class
    std::string name;
    short int strength = 5;
    short int endurance = 5;
    short int agility = 5;
    short int w1 = 77;
    short int w2 = 50;
    short int pointsRemaining = 10;
    char choice;

public:

    //Getters
    std::string Getname();

    //Methods
    void setup();
    void input();
    void addPoints();
    void summary();
};
```

**CharacterCreator.cpp**

```
#include "CharacterCreator.h"

//Methods
void CharacterCreator::summary()
{
    system("cls");

    std::cout << std::setw(w1) << "**************************\n";
    std::cout << std::setw(w1) << "*   Character creation   *\n";
    std::cout << std::setw(w1) << "**************************\n";
    std::cout << "Summary: \n\n";
    std::cout << "Character name: " << name << '\n';
    std::cout << "Strength: " << strength << '\n';
    std::cout << "Endurance: " << endurance << '\n';
    std::cout << "Agility: " << agility << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Press any key to start the game...\n";
    _getch();
}
```

**player.h**

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<string>

class Player
{
private:

    //Variables defining Player class
    std::string name;
    short int strength;
    short int endurance;
    short int agility;
    short int level;

public:

};
```

I tried some things but none of them were really efficent, having in mind that there will be more classes and they will use variables from others.

Comment: What did you try and what is your actual goal? What variable do you want to move?

Comment: You can declare `Player` as friend in `CharacterCreator` class `friend class Player` now will able to access private members in `Player`

Comment: I wanted to move stat values(strength, endurance, agility) from character creator to player class

Comment: Why not just create a `Player` directly from within the creator and return that? You could add a `Player` constructor to make it easier: `Player(std::string n, short s, short e, short a, short l) : name(std::move(n)), strength(s), endurance(e), agility(a), level(l) {}`

Comment: Most code is unrelated to the question. Could you minimize the code to class with one or two members. Remove user input...

Comment: You should really show the things you tried. It would help people to understand what you are trying to achieve and what you are unhappy with. Without that information someone will probably just repeat what you already tried and rejected.

Comment: CharacterCreator does not need to be a class, and if stats are moved around, lump them in a struct

Comment: This does not sound like a task for inheritance unlike some of the answers assume. Put the stats into a separate class (or struct) and just return this class (type) by value.

Comment: This really does not sound like something you should be using inheritance for. Maybe create a `struct` for your stats? But why does a `CharacterCreator` class even need stats? Surely stats are something unique to each player and nothing to do with the creator class - unless you want to store some default values maybe?

Comment: Whether inheritance should be used from a semantic level can be typically determined by the question: *Is* the child a parent? *Is* the Player a Creator? If the child just *has* a parent or *handles* a parent or the other way around, inheritance typically is not the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

Class names are bit confusing.

Anyway, if the CharacterCreator has the responsibility of creating the player, it can directly set the values when calling the constructor of the player class.

Otherwise (i.e. player and CharacterCreator classes have different kind of a relationship), if the player class objects want to access values of a CharacterCreator class object without using inheritance, we can keep a reference of the CharacterCreator object as a member in player class.
Another option is to use friend classes.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the inheritance for now, especially relation between "Creator" and "Player". If you want to be able to construct a `Player` with different values, simply define a constructor:

```
class Player {
public:
    Player(std::string name, int strength): _name{name}, _strength{strength} {}
    std::string getName() { return _name; }
    int getStrength() { return _strength; }
    // more interfaces
private:
    std::string _name;
    int _strength;
};
```

Then later if it seems to you that explicitly creating a `Player` obscures your intents too much, you might consider delegating the creation to a function that will create/build a player:

```
Player createStrongPlayer(std::string name) {
    return Player{name, 100};
}
Player createWeakPlayer(std::string name) {
    return Player{name, 1};
}
```

Then, if you prefer, you can make these "factory" functions a friends of your `Player`, and make a constructor private - this will prevent you from accidentally creating a `Player` that might violate some invariants related to your game (like dunno characterClass == "warrior" and very low strength).

Then, if that is still not enough, read about Builder Pattern, or Abstract Factory (careful here!). Just don't go blindly towards inheritance, like [person - student model](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/436738/why-is-inheritance-bad-in-a-person-student-model), because it seems unlikely you need it in your project's current state.

Comment: Fully agree with the solution. Just as caveat: The `getName()` member function returns a `std::string` as a reference to the caller, i.e. the returned value (unless saved as a copy) is only valid as long as the underlying `Player` object is alive.

Comment: @Sebastian yeah, a bit premature optimization with that const ref. `std::string` representing a name surely is not a huge amount of data to care about copy.

Comment: My last comment referred to a previous version of the code in the answer. The current version probably is a bit easier for the OP. And prevents possible bugs like `player2.setName(player1.getName().append("_2"));`, which would have changed the names of both players. (Assuming a `setName()` member function is introduced.)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a lot of unnecessary code. By moving, I assume you want to pass some values from a class to another.

The proper approach would be called `inheritance`. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Inheritance). Basically you have a `Base` class which defines properties that `derive` classes can inherit from it.

I will give you a very simple example and try to translate it to suit your need.

```
#include <iostream>

class Creator {
    int age;
public:
    Creator() : age(0)
    {
    }
    Creator(int m) : age(m)
    {
    }

    int get_age()
    {
        return age;
    }
};

class Player : public Creator {
    int age;
public:
    Player() : Creator(0)
    { 
        age = get_age();
    }
    Player(int n) : Creator(n)
    {
        age = get_age();
    }

};

int main()
{
    Player p(25);
    std::cout << p.get_age();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `Player::age`? `Player` already inherits a `Creator::age` member...